# Angular UI sref-active working with abstract parent state?

Tags: angularjs, angular-ui-router

I create a sidebar in a directive and append `ui-sref-active="active"` to all elements.

I must be having an issue targeting my states, or something with the abstract parent state is causing the ui-sref-active directive not to work..

In my routes I have:

```
$stateProvider.
state('main', {
  url: '',
  abstract: true,
  template: '<div ui-view=""></div>',
  resolve:{
    otherCharts: function($q, $timeout, secondaryCharts){
      var deferred = $q.defer();
      var charts;
      $timeout(function() {
        charts = secondaryCharts.getSecondaryCharts();
        deferred.resolve(charts);
      }, 250);
      return deferred.promise;
    }
  }
}).
state('dashboard', {
  parent: 'main',
  url: '/dashboard/',
  templateUrl: '/app/free/templates/dashboard.html',
  controller: function($scope, secondaryCharts){
    $scope.secondaryCharts = secondaryCharts.getSecondaryCharts();
  },
  data: {
    name: 'Dashboard'
  }
}).
state('growth', {
  parent: 'main',
  url: '/dashboard/growth',
  templateUrl: '/app/free/modules/donor-growth/donor-growth.html',
  controller: 'make-donor-growth',
  data: {
    name: 'Donor Growth',
    id: 0,
    type: 'chart'
  }
})
```

Then, in my html I have:

```
<li ui-sref="dashboard" ui-sref-active="active" href="/dashboard/"   class="title Dashboard"><a "ui-sref="dashboard" href="/dashboard/"><i class="fa fa-tachometer"></i>Dashboard</a></li>
```

Yet, when I am on a specific state such as myapp.com/dashboard the active class is not being added.. Where am I going wrong targeting my state?

Thanks in advance!